# T test in r: How to change the x and y arguments of a t-test using a lapply function

Tags: r, arguments, t-test, hypothesis-test

I have this dataframe:

[image]

I'm performing a t_test using this lapply approach:

```
columns = colnames(my_data)[-1]
my_t_test<-lapply(my_data[columns], function(x) t.test(x~my_data$Treatment,alternative='less'))
```

But it seems the **t_test** take `x=my_data$Control` and `y=my_data$Stress`, making the results a non-sense. As I'm testing the alternative hypothesis that the difference in the mean is less in the `$Stress` group, I want that the x argument will be `my_data$Stress`. And option is to change to `alternative='greater'`, but is an awful approach, the other option is to change the order of the groups in my dataframe, but I´m looking for a programmatic solution.

any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have `factor` column.  Here, you are using the formula method.  It may be better to do `function(x) t.test(val ~ Treatment, data = data.frame(val = x, Treatment = my_data$Treatment))`

Comment: I think you are confused. If the is the way that your dataframe is displayed in an R console session then the column names, ie. the variable names are ‘21’, ‘28’, ‘35’, ...

Comment: @akrun,is not working, by the way, I changed the order of my dataframe putting the Stress rows first, but the result is the same. I'm confused

Comment: @DavidLópez can you please use `dput` of the example to test thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can use the formula method after subsetting the columns of 'my_data' by looping over the column name vector

```
lapply(columns, function(nm) t.test(.~ Treatment, my_data[c('Treatment', nm)]))
```